# bash: remove empty parameter

Tags: bash, eval

I wonder if it's possible to reduce the last four lines in the following example:

```
#!/bin/bash

function xxx {
  echo $#
  echo $1
}

[[ -n $SOME_ENV ]] && P="-Dabc=$SOME_ENV"

if [[ -n $P ]]; then
  xxx "$P" abc
else
  xxx abc
fi
```

Replacing the if-else-fi by just

```
xxx "$P" abc
```

does work if $P is not empty, otherwise not because "" still counts as empty parameter. Omitting the quotes around $P does not work if SOME_ENV contains spaces.
I know that it's possible with "eval", but eval is evil: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Any other solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I like [using an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38445399/68587) the best. An alternative, for what it's worth, is to use [alternate value](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) substitution.

```
xxx ${P:+"$P"} abc
```

This will be substituted with `"$P"` if `$P` is set and not blank. If it is empty, the entire word is removed. The neat thing is you could get rid of `$P` altogether.

```
xxx ${SOME_ENV:+"-Dabc=$SOME_ENV"} abc
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use an options variable, `p`, make it an array:

```
p=()
[[ -n $SOME_ENV ]] && p+=("-Dabc=$SOME_ENV")

xxx "${p[@]}" abc
```

If `p` is empty, then `"${p[@]}"` expands to nothing, just as you want.

For example, with `SOME_ENV` unset, `$#` is 1 as it should be:

```
$ bash script
1
abc
```

With `SOME_ENV` set, then `$#` is 2 as it should be:

```
$ SOME_ENV='1 2 3' bash script
2
-Dabc=1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You already test the length of `$SOME_ENV` and set `$P` only when `$SOME_ENV` is not empty. `$P` and `$SOME_ENV` are either both empty or both non-empty. Do you have any good reason to test `$P`?

I would merge the two tests and then just make `$P` disappear (it is just a temporary variable in the code you posted). Something like this:

```
if [[ -n $SOME_ENV ]]; then
  xxx -Dabc="$SOME_ENV" abc
else
  xxx abc
fi
```

Comment: Your solution is perfect if one would keep the last 4 lines. But i want to get rid of it. My intention is to have only one line starting with "xxx". The real example contains much more that just a common "abc". I want to avoid that redundancy.